# My answer was deleted, why?

Tags: support, faq

I posted an answer to a question and it's been deleted. Why!?

---

As we head in to [Ubuntu 11.10 release](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1832/psa-11-10-release-today-aka-lets-get-rockin) I'd like to make sure when we are going through the site and marking items for removal in this (and any) clean up period we're leaving notices to users as to *what is really* going on.

This is designed to be a Community Wiki FAQ where each answer is a brief reason why a post may be deleted and how to remedy this. Please at least leave a comment with at least a link to the reason why the post is (or is flagged to be) delete.

Answer (score 6):

### The answer should have been a comment

We require that users [gain 50 reputation points](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment) before they're able to post a comment. If, in the meanwhile, you post a comment *as an answer*, we will delete it.

The *Post Answer* button may only ever be used for actual answers to the question.

Note that you can always leave comments on your own question and its answers. If you want to add more information, add it to the question itself!

If you just want to say thanks, this worked for me, accept the answer by clicking the green check-mark, and don't forget to *vote up*. This is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying *thank you*.

Answer (score 5):

## Asking a new question in the Answer section

If you have a new question, or a similar situation not resolved by the current question, please [Ask a new Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) instead of posting that question in the answer section. This site is [designed to handle one question per post](https://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion) - posting your question in the answer portion of another post will result in it not being handled properly.

Answer (score 4):

## Abusive or not constructive

In order to maintain Stack Exchange and Ask Ubuntu's primary goal of professional high quality Q&A site abusive and non-constructive (noise) answers will be removed. There are ample areas of this [site](http://chat.askubuntu.com/) and the [Ubuntu Network](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/webforums) at large to hold discussion and voice opinions, the answer section of this site does not serve that purpose.

Not only are abusive posts against the [rules](https://askubuntu.com/faq#etiquette) of Ask Ubuntu they violate the [Ubuntu Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct). You'll be issued a warning with a potential for suspension if abusive conduct continues.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer contains nothing but a URL

If your answer just contains a link, it **might** be deleted. We prefer you answer the question rather than defering it to someone else, somewhere else:

> An analogy would be if you are standing at 100 Main St. and you ask
>   where 98 Main St. is. A good answer would be
>
> > "It is the next building over". *points at building*
>
> If you instead include a link, you are saying
>
> > "I'll direct you to a tourism information booth, and they will be
> >     able to provide you with your answer and much more!"

Of course, if the answer is the only solution to the problem, we won't delete it. Please always try to directly include the essential parts of the answer, and provide the link for reference.

See also:

- [Should I flag answers with just a link to another site?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1765/should-i-flag-answers-with-just-a-link-to-another-site)
- [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)