# PSA: 11.10 Release today! (aka. let's get rockin')

Tags: discussion, community

I know, I know, I always put out [a warning](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1163/psa-11-04-release-day), but release time is usually when more users start using Ubuntu and as a bonus this time Ask Ubuntu is featured in the Ubuntu installer slider show:

[image]

Some tips for helping when the site gets busy:

- Lots of new attention and traffic means it's usually an influx of duplicate questions, especially the easy ones, so keep an eye out for dupes.
- Some users don't write descriptive questions, editing as they come in is very useful and helps point people in the right direction. No one wants to read an entire page of "ubuntu 11.10 firefox problem" style questions.
- When we're really busy sometimes people stumble over each other on the brand new incoming questions -- I hit pages 2-3 during the release to find questions that might have been bumped off too soon.
- Check out these [pro forma comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-pro-forma-comments-do-you-use), they help when trying to guide new users.

Who knows, this might lead to a nice influx of new users, so good luck everyone, I get the feeling we're going to be busy!

Comment: Yes, we sure are going to be busy... if past releases are any indication.

Comment: Answer 'cannon' at the ready.

Comment: Cooooooooooooooool :D

Comment: hey, that's really cool!

Comment: Well the whole site has too many good questions with very good answers. Am guessing more than 70% of all typical questions users will have are already answered. Also with my new PRECISE POLLO! avatar users will come in masses... if they are hungry.

Comment: i've temporarily "featured" this meta post-- please feel free to unfeature in a few days

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is a great site. Thank you everybody who contributes time and answers!

Comment: Now we're getting swamped! Dig deep!

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing :) We're really getting hit now with a lot of new users.

Answer (score 1):

The release is past and we are looking forward to the next release which is preceeded by a beta release, see [PSA: 12.04 Beta Has Landed](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2642/psa-12-04-beta-has-landed).