# Time Frame of Abandoned/Old Questions

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I have checked the following questions:

[What to do with abandoned questions?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1843/what-to-do-with-abandoned-questions)

[How should we define "Abandoned" as a close reason?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2468/how-should-we-define-abandoned-as-a-close-reason)

[Changes to how we close abandoned questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2813/changes-to-how-we-close-abandoned-questions)

[Closing abandoned questions is harder than it should be.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2329/closing-abandoned-questions-is-harder-than-it-should-be)

And I have not seen an answer to a particular doubt I have about the time.

For example, what should constitute an abandoned question. For me it should be a question that is not affected by the current Ubuntu release. For example, if the question is in regard to a problem in the Ubuntu 11.10 version, then, until a new release appears, the "countdown" for the abandoned status should not start.

After a new release is made, typically most people update to the latest. This increase might help solve some of this question if by chance somebody sees it and finds that it was fixed on the new release. If this is not the case, the OP should check in a time period of at least half the release cycle (3 months) to see if the new Ubuntu release fixes the problem. If not, he or she should update the tag to reflect that it was tested on a new release and it is still a current problem.

This way, moderators and helpers know that if a question is on the current Ubuntu version of is at least 9 months old with no changes, then it can be thought to be an abandoned question. There are several users that might still be waiting after 5 months for example for a solution to a question and not find it until a new releases comes out. If they do, then good, question is answered. If not they can update the tag to reflect the new version. If they don't flag it or test the new version, then it is most likely a forgotten question that will surely be abandoned.

But the point is that a time frame could be added to abandoned question so that at least 6 months need to pass to start giving the question a doubtful eye. If the 9 month period arrives then that question is pregnant with an abandoned flag.

Sorry for the english, If something was written wrong or confuses let me know. Just wanted to clear the time frame about abandoned questions.

Comment: My personal reference is any question that was asked before I joined the site, which is anything older than September 2011. I will add an answer when I get back later on, with reasons why I have it as a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think:
a) if a question references a package that is no longer fully updated.

b) if an OP doesn't respond to "is this still an issue" in a couple days

c) questions with exceedingly low rep judged with more stringent guidelines - e.g. if they only asked one question and they're probably never going to accept an answer since it wasn't instant

Summary:
It's about keeping the QA:
a) relatively clean
b) devoid of questions that despite best efforts to solve a problem aren't meeting with user response

Comment: You made several important points there. The one that I think is very important is B. Thanks aking.

Answer (score 1):

Eeek! I pretty much forgot about this question until now. Anyway, let me get to answering this.

I have set myself the release date of 11.10 as a cut-off mark for deciding the abandoned questions. This actually helps me take decisions easier. I don't want to go around asking people if they would consider it or not.

**OK, but why the release date?**

Most of us would know that people hear about Ubuntu on the release date and would pretty much forget about it until the next release date. Having their questions closed when they return once again (if they return, that is) wouldn't be too nice. And, if they still have a problem, hopefully they will reply to the comments. I am not saying that this will definitely happen but rather just a blind hope that they will eventually return.

And, I joined the site just a while before 11.10 and I feel it hasn't been too long since then. Why close the questions so quickly?

---

You have every right to agree or disagree with the points I raised. They are in no way binding to anyone other than myself and I only use them as a guideline to take decisions. You can fall back to my thoughts or have your own, as you wish.

Comment: +1 because of the cut-off mark about 11.10 which is a sensible way of doing it. Thanks again jokerdino.