# Is AU more a hotline or a knowledge base?

Tags: discussion

Trying to help a little and reading some meta (hot) posts, I went across this question.

It's a general way to convey some doubts like this one: replying to someone is often a dialectic process, not merely giving a solution. In other words, it's driving the OP to find a solution with questions and tests suggestions in comments (not in answers). What to do when done (when the OP tells "Hurray, thanks a lot" and so on). Most often, the answer exists not, or could be rewritten and elaborated.

- Not important if AU is more a hotline, because the important thing is to unlock the user problem.
- Important if AU is more a knowledge base. Then editing the answers to make them more general and accurate, tagging correctly and so on is important. But this takes time, so is it really useful ?

What's you opinion on this ?

Comment: "this question"? What question?

Comment: The title itself is the question (mark the question mark).

Comment: Related http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2436/how-can-we-refocus-on-being-a-qa-not-a-support-forum-or-bug-tracker and http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8375/169736

Comment: When you say "I went across this question" you don't mean *another* question, but the question "is AU a hotline?"?

Comment: That's right... BTW, the links you quoted pinpoint problems, and tell what should be done (in OP opinion). I don't, I only ask if there is a general opinion about this.

Comment: "But this takes time, so is it really useful ?"- Yes, editing and cleaning up posts is very useful.

Comment: Why does it have to be one or the other?

Comment: @Rinzwind: I think I had explained why it's a practical problem to me.

Comment: Thing is: answers need to be correct. Nothing more. Some questions need long knowledge base looking answers and others need a quick short answer. Why can't AU be both?