# PSA: 12.04 Launches this week, steel yourselves!

Tags: discussion, community

Release is *this week*, which means that we'll have people who are going to start asking questions here, so we need to stay on our toes, update existing questions (more below), and just generally keep an eye on things so we don't get battered like we did for 11.10's release cycle.

Other than the HUD there's not many major user-visible changes, so we can likely just update questions by removing the version tag and making them more general, so they likely need some minor editing as well.

Comment: PSA: PSA = Public Service Announcement.

Answer (score 9):

### Things we can do to make the next few weeks suck less

(Add your own!)

Important ones:

We get swamped with new questions. Other than answering questions, one of the most important things you can do is [review questions](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=day). This ensures that horrible questions get fixed and updated. You need at least 125 reputation to start reviewing and the Strunk and White badge:

- [Review incoming questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/improved-reviewing/). If we get at least 10 people doing this once a day for the next few weeks we'll be rocking it! Note that the efforts of reviewing, such as finding duplicates, can be improved by coordinating it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) such as via [the room Ubuntu Regulators](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/206/ubuntu-regulators).

Nice to have:

- [Editing tips and tricks](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks)
- [Style guide for questions and answers](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers)
- [What prewritten Pro-forma (aka AutoReviewComments) userscript comments can we use and share?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1323/what-prewritten-pro-forma-userscript-comments-can-we-use-and-share) (If you're planning on helping out with incoming questions, please install this, it makes it much easier.)
- A good deal of questions don't need to be version tagged with [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.04), save those  for hardware specific questions, or things that are drastically different inbetween versions that require it. Remember we strive to keep questions up to date over time, so keeping questions updated that apply to multiple versions helps us, having the version in the body is usually enough anyway.