# In an answer, should I link to the same question found on Unix&Linux Stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Take this question: [What are some typical uses of hard links?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226063)

I found the exact same question in the Unix&Linux Stack Exchange site: [Why do hard links exists?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20670/9041)

Should I post an answer with a link to this question? If I do, it gets converted automatically to a comment.

Normally, we would discourage short answers with just a link. However, considering that the link is pointing to another Stack Exchange website, where answers can be edited and voted on, surely it's OK?

I can't flag the question as a duplicate, because the duplicate isn't on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: "because the duplicate isn't on AskUbuntu" does that not tell you it is not considered a dupe and therefor a valid question?

Comment: So should I really copy and paste the answers from U&L, crediting the source?

Comment: I already did that for you somewhat ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer as you normally would (with the "full" answer text), use the U&L as source.

Just linking to it negates the use of the question as a Q&A article and thus is discouraged - even in this scenario. Stick to comments if you don't want to create a dupe, answer "properly" if you want it as an actual answer.

Comment: Is creating a dupe an option though? I would love to flag the question as a dupe of one in U&L.

Comment: SE does not allow to mark dupes across different SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to answer your question with a link to the best answer of an identical question: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1766/95681

Not really. :P
Basically, you need to answer their question, then cite the source. The important thing is that *your answer needs to answer their question*. Citing sources is recommended (1, it's a good practice; and 2, the user might need more detail than you provided,) but, when answering their question, **answer their question**.

If you see a  link-only answer, then you basically have 2 options:

1. Downvote theirs, and post your own answer. (If you don't know anything about the question, look at the link that was posted. Then, you can sound like an expert while *actually* previously knowing nothing and gaining from the very answer that you downvoted. >:)
2. Suggest an edit to theirs.